# How can I get a return value from a post request sent from javascript to flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post

New to flask here. I need to pass an integer variable from html/javascript to python flask in order to perform a calculation and return the result value to javascript so that I can display it on the DOM without refreshing the page. Below is the HTML structure I'm dealing with.

```
<form action="/buy" method="post" id="buy-form">

    <h4>Price</h4>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="limit-price"
      name="limit-price"
    />

    <h4>Quantity</h4>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="limit-quantity"
      name="limit-quantity"
    />

    <button type="button" id="maximize-buy">Max</button>

    <input type="submit" name="buy" value="BUY" id="submit-buy" />

</form>
```

I want to pass the value thats typed into the **`limit-price`** text input over into flask (using Javascript) at the click of the **`maximize-buy`** button in order to perform a calculation in python flask and then return that result back to Javascript so that I can display it on the page without refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ajax`

```
<form>
..... your form..
<div id="div-id></div>
</form>

<script>
data ={
   price = $('#limit-price').val(),
   quantity = $('#limit-quantity').val()
}
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data
  }).done(function (data) {
    $('#div-id').html(data['val']);
  }).fail(function (error) {
    alert(error);
  });
 </script>
```

And create a function in flask

```
@app.route(url)
def calc():
    quantity = request.form['quantity']
    price = request.form['price']
    return jsonify({'val': quantity*price})
```